# trying to center an image in a ul vertically

Tags: css, html-lists, image

Just a quick one about centering images vertically in a horizontal ul nav

https://i.stack.imgur.com/XRDnA.png

I want the F and the Twitter to be centered vertically..

here's my code

```
<div id="nav" class="twelvecol last">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sponsors</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/fb.png"></a></li>
            <li><a href="#"><img src="images/twitter.png"></a></li>             
        </ul>   
    </div>

#nav
{


}

#nav ul
{
    height:60px;
    text-align:center;
    background: #cc0000; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #cc0000 0%, #7c0000 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,#cc0000), color-stop(100%,#7c0000)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  #cc0000 0%,#7c0000 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  #cc0000 0%,#7c0000 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  #cc0000 0%,#7c0000 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  #cc0000 0%,#7c0000 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#cc0000', endColorstr='#7c0000',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */


}

#nav li
{
    display:inline-block;
    font-size:18px;

}

#nav li a
{
    color:#FFF;
    padding-top:20px;
    padding-left:20px;
    padding-right:20px;
    padding-bottom:20px;
    list-style-type:none;
    text-decoration:none;
}

#nav li a:hover{
    background:#F00;

}
```

thanks for any help you can offer

Answer (score 0):

For graphical links to Facebook and Twitter, I would personally use background images replacing text.

Background images mean you can simply use `background-position` and/or `height`, etc., to control the vertical placement.

There are a bunch of approaches listed at http://www.mezzoblue.com/tests/revised-image-replacement/, I prefer using `text-indent`.